# Do you need an "All" filter for chips?

Tags: usability, website-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, users

Im using a filter system that involves using chips to filter by category. You can only select one chip at a time. Does it make sense to have an "all" filter, or to allow the user to deselect the chip to clear the filter? There will be a long horizontal overflow of filter options.

Here are options 1 and options 2, white space represents frame size.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your decision on whether to implement "Clearing the filter" is the key, option 1 is easy, just click on All; but option 2 introduces some anti-patterns, should the user deselect Breakfast, or select all other tags, or scroll to the end and expect to find a reset button? overall it's confusing and really only designed for single-select

On the user side, which option do you think your users will likely to pick? Given that All is one of the choices, Option 1 is already functionally more supreme than the 2, and I like how giving a quantity next to All indicates it's a superset.

Option 1 takes too much space? you might be interested in split buttons or this hover effect: https://dribbble.com/shots/19665650-Bottom-Tab-Exploration

Answer (score 0):

To answer your title question, with this number of choices and **assuming that ALL can be concurrent**, then yes, it makes sense. Otherwise, I'd suggest using ALL only for a "clear all" link (i.e., only to delete, not add, and not as a chip).

As an aside, I'd be very hesitant about using a filter with hidden selections. If you don't have an option, you'll have to test this extensively, but IMHO the results will probably be poor. I think a categorized accordion would be a much better choice, as mentioned [**here**](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/07/frustrating-design-patterns-broken-frozen-filters/#avoid-tiny-scrollable-panes) (although it's a solution for a vertical pane ) or in your particular case, a dropdown would be perfect.